# d3js creates two rectangles

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

```
d3.tsv("ACDFile.tsv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        if (d["Gruppe"] == "Italien") {
            d3.select("svg").selectAll("div")
                .data(d["Service-levelzurzeit[%]"])
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", 30)
                .attr("height", d["Service-levelzurzeit[%]"])
                .style("fill", "blue")
                .html(d["Gruppe"])
                }

    }
)})
```

This creates two rectangles where only one should be created (theres only one "Italien"). anyone can point out what Im missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have two values, comma separated in `Service-levelzurzeit[%]`. Js expects number like `4.15`, but you have `4,15`. For `tsv()` it means array `[4, 15]`.